# How to Print reference number properly in Webographie?

Tags: bibliographies

I am adding references that I have used in report written with `TeX`. I have added this in my `references.bib`

```
@BOOK{Oracle,
author={Oracle official website},
title={http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-whats-new-2157071.html},
publisher={Last seen 20 June 2015},
}
```

The resulting ouput:I get

```
[official website],O.,http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-whats-new-2157071.html,Last seen 20 June 2015
```

But I don't get the reference number like [1]

while it works on other references:

```
@BOOK{wikipedia,
author={Wikipedia},
title={https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizingcompiler},
publisher={Last seen 03 May 2015},
```

}

I get a proper output:

```
[7]Wikipedia,https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizingcompiler,Last seen 03 May 2015
```

Comment: Do you use `biblatex`/`biber` or `bibtex`? Which bibliography style? Can you add a minimal example? (See [How to write a MWEB (Minimal working example with Bibliography)?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/4408))

Comment: I am using `natbibpackage`

Comment: And the `\bibliographystyle`? (A minimal working example, see link above, would have made this clear.)

Comment: Don't get me wrong  here, but Wikipedia is no book, a title is not a url and a publisher is certainly not *Last seen 03 May 2015*. With the old `natbib` system, urls can be provided in the url-field, *IF* the bib-style provides one. Else, it is commonly set in the `howpublished` field. `biblatex` provides an `online` type dedicated to online entries.

Comment: In addition to @Johannes_B's points, that output is not 'proper' according to any bibliography style I'm aware of. The page has a title as well as a URL and the entry should use it.

Answer (score 1):

I have actually find the solution for my question, by adding the `year` into `@Book`. Since it is  `author-year citation mode`. I found this article very useful on `natbib` http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php

Comment: You should really consider switching the field for online entries, there is a very very good reason that there are `book` fields, along with `article`, or `inbook` or `techreport` or `patent` or `misc`/`online`. All follow different rules to be cited and referenced.

Comment: Yes I know, but what is the proper field for a webpage ?

Comment: Bad habit of quoting myself: *With the old natbib system, urls can be provided in the url-field, IF the bib-style provides one. Else, it is commonly set in the howpublished field. biblatex provides an online type dedicated to online entries.*

Comment: Okay I will do it